# Twitter API v1 stream not working with needle in Node JS (getting no data)

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream, twitter-oauth, needle.js

In my project I'm using Twitter API user timeline (both v1 and v2) and filtered stream (v2) with [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle) successfully, but I can't get the v1 version of filtered stream ([statuses/filter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter)) working with needle.

I feel clueless, as needle's streaming works fine with API v2 (just like the [official example](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js)) and I've tested the authentication part (OAuth) of my v1 code and verified that it works well (response code: 200) - yet I'm not getting any data from the stream.

I even tried finding the problem by setting up Fiddler as a proxy of needle, but I saw nothing strange.

I've created an extracted, stand alone version of the v1 streaming module, hoping that someone can spot the issue/bug.

```js
const uuid = require('uuid');
const oauth = require('oauth-sign');
const needle = require('needle');

const keys = {
    twitter: {
        consumerKey: '<your-consumerKey>', //API Key
        consumerSecretKey: '<your-consumerSecretKey>', //API Secret Key
        oauthToken: '<your-oauthToken>', //Access Token
        oauthTokenSecret: '<your-oauthTokenSecret>', //Access Token Secret
    }
};

const streamURL = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json';

const apiParams = {
    'track': 'pizza',
};

function getAuthHeader() {
    const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
    const nonce = uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, '');

    let oauthParams = {
        'oauth_consumer_key': keys.twitter.consumerKey,
        'oauth_nonce': nonce,
        'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp': timestamp,
        'oauth_token': keys.twitter.oauthToken,
        'oauth_version': '1.0'
    };

    let mergedParams = { ...apiParams, ...oauthParams };

    oauthParams['oauth_signature'] = oauth.hmacsign(
        'POST', streamURL, mergedParams, 
        keys.twitter.consumerSecretKey, 
        keys.twitter.oauthTokenSecret
    );

    return Object.keys(oauthParams).sort().map(function (k) {
        return k + '="' + oauth.rfc3986(oauthParams[k]) + '"';
    }).join(', ');
}

function streamConnect(retryAttempt) {
    const stream = needle.post(streamURL, apiParams, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `OAuth ${getAuthHeader()}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        timeout: 20000
    });

    stream.on('header', (statusCode, headers) => {
        console.log(
            `Status: ${statusCode} ` + 
            `(${statusCode === 200 ? 'OK' : 'ERROR'})`
        );
    }).on('data', data => {
        //never receiving any data ???
        console.log('data received:');
        console.log(data);
    }).on('err', error => {
        // This reconnection logic will attempt to reconnect when a disconnection is detected.
        // To avoid rate limits, this logic implements exponential backoff, so the wait time
        // will increase if the client cannot reconnect to the stream. 
        let retryTimeout = 2 ** retryAttempt;
        console.warn(`A connection error occurred: ${error.message}. Reconnecting in ${retryTimeout/1000} seconds...`)
        setTimeout(() => {
            streamConnect(++retryAttempt);
        }, retryTimeout);
    });

    return stream;
}

streamConnect(0);
```

*(I know that there are a couple of libraries that I could use, but 1: I don't want to use one just because of this bug, 2: I truly hate when I can't find a solution for a problem)*